# Best way to resample/re-mesh portion of the screwed up mesh?

Tags: mesh

I've end up with this mesh. You can see it has vertices that connected to many edges in a star formation. It causes those faces to stick out and making sculpting harder.

I am looking for a way to re-mesh those regions with some more uniformal pattern, so I can smooth it out in sculpting.

Alternatively I was imagining some method of sculpting AND adding more details at the same time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end Iv'e used combination of methods. I think it would be sufficient for me to use only one - Dyntopo while sculpting. This video was very helpful in understanding how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FTRK5uo6T0&ab_channel=SirPinkBeard
In my case I've already worked on UV and so, I had to learn another thing - Data Transfer modifier, which allowed me to transfer my UV stuff into a new mesh.